# How do I define more than 9 points in a tikzset with the let operation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

As shown in the code below `\p10` will make an error, preventing long drawings.

How does one overcome this?

I think this is asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516609/theres-any-way-to-create-a-tikzset-function-with-more-than-9-arguments) but the answer is unclear for this aplication.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{my doodle/.pic=%
{%
    \coordinate (-A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (-B) at (1cm, 0);
    \coordinate (-C) at (1cm, -1cm);
    \coordinate (-D) at (0, -1cm);
    \draw[line width=1.5mm,red!40!orange!30!yellow] (-A) -- (-B) -- (-C) -- (-D) -- cycle; % gold rectangle
    % blue line
    \coordinate (-D1) at (-0.055cm,-1.07cm);                                % starting point of blue line
    \path let \p1=(-D1) in coordinate (-D2) at (-0.25cm,\y1+0.1cm);         % go to starting position of pattern
    \path let \p2=(-D2) in coordinate (-D3) at (-0.1cm,\y2-0.05cm);         % step 1
    \path let \p3=(-D3) in coordinate (-D4) at (-0.25cm,\y3+0.25cm);        % step 2
    \path let \p4=(-D4) in coordinate (-D5) at (-0.1cm,\y4-0.05cm);         % step 3
    \path let \p5=(-D5) in coordinate (-D6) at (-0.25cm,\y5-0.05cm);        % step 1
    \path let \p6=(-D6) in coordinate (-D7) at (-0.1cm,\y6+0.25cm);         % step 2
    \path let \p7=(-D7) in coordinate (-D8) at (-0.25cm,\y7-0.05cm);        % step 3
    \path let \p8=(-D8) in coordinate (-D9) at (-0.1cm,\y8-0.05cm);         % step 1
    \path let \p9=(-D9) in coordinate (-D10) at (-0.25cm,\y9+0.25cm);   % step 2
    \path let \p10=(-D10) in coordinate (-D11) at (-0.1cm,\y10-0.05cm);     
    \draw[thick, blue] (-D1) -- (-D2) -- (-D3) -- (-D4) -- (-D5) -- (-D6) -- (-D7) -- (-D8) -- (-D9) -- (-D10) -- (-D11);%
    }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\doodle}{ O{black} O{0.18pt} r() }{
     \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \pic[draw=#1, line width=#2] 
        at (#3) {my doodle};
    \end{tikzpicture}    
}

\doodle(0,-2)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP answered his own question.

Comment: @SebGlav a self-answer is no reason to close

Comment: OK, sorry, I thought that the answer was obvious enough to not need more than this self answer, actually.

Comment: @SebGlav Why not close as "the question is too trivial" then. But then I don't think trivial questions should be closed (unless it's a typo) – even on SO (in principle) // [Is closing a question as off-topic for being answered in the comments a valid close reason on this site? - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/is-)  // [questions answered by pointing out simple typos - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/)

Comment: Closed or not this answer should not be deleted. I could not find such an answer to solve my problem and that cost me time. This could be closed but should stay here for people to see.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on the solution by accident - changing both `\p10` and `\y10` to `\p{10}` **AND** `\y{10}`.

The problem is the 0, or any second number.

Comment: I think that the number is actually an argument to the macro `\p`, so without the braces only the first number is grabbed by the macro.